# Prevent spam calls to webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services, spam-prevention

I have a page on my MVC site with multiple items the user can click to add to their basket.

Upon clicking 'Add' I perform a $.ajax() command to call the backend and perform a calculation, returning the result and updating a price on the page.

It was recently discovered that clicking many 'Add' buttons in quick succession means the user waits for each call to process in turn. That is, they click 10 'Add' buttons and they see the price change 10 times.

**I am not concerned with the UI**. What I *am* concerned about is that the webservice call can be spammed, which in turn could put a strain on the database server because each request requires a database lookup and other calculations.

I have started to put a "locking" flag in like this to stop Joe Public clicking lots of times.

```
var flag=0;

function updateBasket() {
    if (flag = 0) {
        flag = 1; // Processing
        var form = $("#ItemsForm");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateBasket")',
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                // code
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // code
            }
        });
        flag = 0;
    } else {
        // Still processing previous request
        alert('please wait');
    }
```

**HOWEVER** this can surely be circumvented by going into the console and executing

```
flag=0;updateBasket();
```

What can I do in the backend to prevent this call being spammed? I am concerned with the code, which I control, rather than network-infrastructure level.

UPDATE: Checking the user's credentials (username0 is not possible because they can do this without logging in.
If I added a unique value to the form on page load that is serialised I could check that in the back end against when I last saw it, but all the attacker would do would be $('#uniqueValue').val('newValue); and negate that.

UPDATE: Just a reminder that I control the MVC backend, which is making the call to the database server. Here is where I think I can prevent spam calls to the database, but I don't know how.

Comment: Is there anything on the form that uniquely identifies that form/user (or do you use any form of authentication) ?  (I'm guessing there must be if they are 'adding' something, even if they are currently anonymous)   If so, you could use this server side to check how many requests made (eg in the last minute) *by that user* then return an error "too many requests" prior to accessing the database.

Comment: In general, you don't want to block the ajax call at the time the ajax call is made (as in your code) - instead, block/disable the *add* button until the ajax call returns.

Comment: If your `#uniqueValue` was a token generated server-side that you validated, then no, they couldn't just put a new value in because then they'd get a validation error.  But that would require an extra call to get the token and perhaps that could be spammed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would isolate all of my JavaScript away from the end user, doing something like this.

```
(function () {
    function updateBasket() {
       ...
    }
})();
```

Doing this would mean that `updateBasket()` couldn't be called in the console.

This is called a self executing anonymous function. There is a great article on it here: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: "I am not concerned with the UI."

Comment: @freedomn-m What does this have to do with UI?

Comment: While this goes some way to stop the obvious `flag=0` in the console, it wouldn't stop someone that knows js.  `updateBasket()` can still be called, just not the *same* updateBasket that you've defined...

Comment: I am advocating changing the JavaScript, JavaScript is not the UI.

Comment: Changing the js won't stop the issue, stated as "What I am concerned about is that the webservice call..."

Comment: It's not semantics JavaScript is a scripting language. Is NodeJS all UI? No, its a server-side JavaScript.

Comment: "What can I do in the backend to prevent this call being spammed" - are you saying you think *this* JS is on the "backend" webservice?

Comment: Clearly not but the OP specifically calls out being able to run the JavaScript as what hes trying to prevent. "I am concerned with the code, which I control, rather than network-infrastructure level." The only code that is shown is the JavaScript, so this is all we can assist with.

Comment: @freedomn-m if you have a better answer please contribute, there's a lot of stuff that could be done server side but we have no detail to assist with server side.

Comment: Summary: doesn't answer the question. which asks about controlling the webservice/backend.